# Advanced Data Grid support in Dojo

Tags: dojo

I am looking for Hirerarchal structure support in Data Grid in Dojo API.
I searched on it but didn't find out anything on this. any help on this will be appreciable.

Comment: I think the new dgrid has hierarchical structure support.

Comment: Hi... Thanks for the inputs but i didn't find any Hirerarchal structure support in new Dojo API. Could you please refer me to the link, if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

How about dojox.grid.TreeGrid? Reference guide: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/grid/TreeGrid.html